# LIKE operator not working in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

this is my code  when i run it

```
$name=$_GET['name'];
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM category WHERE name LIKE =" .$name;

$rs = mysql_query($strSQL);

// Loop the recordset $rs
$response = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {


    $product = array();
    $product["id"] = $row["id"];
    $product["name"] = $row["name"];
    array_push($response, $product);
}

echo json_encode($response);
}
error:mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs))
```

it shows error on  this line help me to fix this

Comment: stop using deprecated+removed library of `mysql_*`. start using `mysqli_*` OR `PDO` along with `prepared statements`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have inserted wrong syntax ....use this

```
 $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM category WHERE name LIKE '%$name'";
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because You are not sending Query matched with your datatype of the **name** field.

Try below syntax with ''

```
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM category WHERE name LIKE '" .$name . "'";
```

IF you still getting the same error then try this code

```
$name=$_GET['name'];
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM category WHERE name LIKE '" .$name . "'";

$rs = mysql_query($strSQL);
if(mysql_num_rows($rs) > 0){
// Loop the recordset $rs
$response = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {


    $product = array();
    $product["id"] = $row["id"];
    $product["name"] = $row["name"];
    array_push($response, $product);
}

echo json_encode($response);
}
}
else{ echo json_encode(array('msg'=>"No records found")); }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to open a connection to your database. Something like:

```
<?php
$dbhost = 'localhost:3036';
$dbuser = 'root';
$dbpass = 'rootpassword';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
$name=$_GET['name'];
$strSQL = "SELECT * FROM category WHERE name LIKE '%" .$name . "%'";
// $strSQL = "SELECT * FROM category WHERE name = '" .$name . "'";

$rs = mysql_query($strSQL, $conn);

// Loop the recordset $rs
$response = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)) {


    $product = array();
    $product["id"] = $row["id"];
    $product["name"] = $row["name"];
    array_push($response, $product);
}

echo json_encode($response);
?>
```

Also if you are going to use "LIKE" in your sql, you don't use "=".